# Define a function on a single element but linear in sums

Tags: functions, condition

I have tried searching around but I couldn't find the solution to this very simple setup. I want to define a function $f(x)$, which should satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and whose action I only want to define on a single term $x$. In practice I would like something like

```
f[x_]/;(some condition that forces x to be a single term with no sums) := Module[{},...]
f[x_+y_] := f[x] + f[y]
```

What is this condition that verifies that $x$ has no sum involved ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just reorder the two definitions, so that the one for sums comes first. You can read more about it in the tutorial [_The Ordering of Definitions_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#26982). ``f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y];
f[x_] := x^2;
f[a + b]
(* a^2 + b^2 *)`` However, what should happen for something like `f[a/b]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reorder the two definitions, so that the one for sums comes first. You can read more about it in the tutorial [*The Ordering of Definitions*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#26982).

```
f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y]
f[x_] := x^2

f[a + b]
(* a^2 + b^2 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" )

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your problem statement is ambiguous. How should `f[2 + 3]` be handled? Should it be `f[5]` or `f[2] + f[3]`

That is, as Domen suggested?

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y]
f[x_] := x^2

f[2 + 3]

(* 25 *)
```

Or with a slight modification?

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y]
f[x_] := x^2

f[2 + 3]

(* 13 *)
```

This arises because your underlying definition is not linear.

Comment: My function is linear in this trivial case of explicit numbers. My function is (schematically) simplifying projectors via pattern matching. I want $f[a_1 \Pi \Pi + a_2 \mathrm{Tr} \Pi + ...] = a_1 \Pi + a_2 (D-1)$ , but for pattern matching and for some conditions it's much better to treat term by term.